# Check whether we are using Eclipse 32 bit version or 64 bit version

Tags: java, eclipse, bit

I want to check in a java program whether the underlying eclipse is 32 bit or 64 bit.
I have tried System.getProperty(os.arch/orgi.platform) etc but they are not giving correct results.

P.S. I have installed 32-bit as well as 64-bit eclipse on 64-bit Windows7.

Main problem is : i am getting one pointer using org.eclipse.swt.internal.ole.win32.COM class method which returns int in 32 bit and long in 64 bit. I want to handle this independent of underlying eclipse version.

Comment: Why are you using an internal SWT class?

Answer (score 3):

Open the file `eclipse.ini` in the Eclipse installation directory and observe the 4th line - in my case:

```
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.0.200.v20090519
```

The `x86_64` part corresponds to it being the 64-bit version.

For the 32-bit version it would just say `x86`, here's an example from a recent Eclipse Neon (4.6.1):

```
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.400.v20160518-1444
```

Comment: Thanks, but i want to check in java program so that my code works on both 32 bit and 64 bit eclipse

Answer (score 1):

In an Eclipse plugin use `Platform.getOSArch()` (Platform is `org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform`). Platform also has a number of `ARCH_xxx` constants for the various architectures.

Comment: Can't i use it in nornal java program which is not a plugin code?

Comment: No this is Eclipse plugin only.

Comment: the method is COM.moveMemory(int,TCHAR,int) in 32 bit and COM.moveMemory(long,TCHAR,int) in 64 bit. i have int/long variable.Now i want my code to call the corresponding method.

Comment: These classes are internal and are not part of the SWT API and consequently should not be used directly.

Comment: This scenario can be with any method instead of these internal API. In that generic case how to handle this?